# Angular: reuse page skeleton between routes

Tags: angular, angular-router

Consider a web site laid out as two separate components, perhaps a navbar and a main content area. The navbar varies a little between pages; it is a single component parameterized by a small dictionary. On the other hand, the main content area contains a completely different component on each page.

I would like to implement one "skeleton" component and reuse it between routes:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='navbar'>...</div>
  <div class='content'>...</div>
</div>
```

How do I plug the navbar and the content into this?

I considered using auxiliary routes or child routes, but either approach feels very heavyweight considering that the two components shouldn't evolve separately. They should probably be implemented as part of the same route, if Angular supports that somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider this as some abc component
HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <ng-content select="[navbar]">...</ng-content>
  <ng-content select="[maincontent]">...</ng-content>
</div>
```

HTML Let's conside this as some other component which is passing html to abc component like this.

```
<abc>
<ng-container navbar> Content for navbar goes here... <ng-container>
<ng-container mainContent> Content for mainContent goes here... <ng-container>
</abc>
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I've also found that I can define `<ng-template>` objects and pass them as `@Input() ... TemplateRef` to the container, which then inlines them using `*ngTemplateOutlet`.